# In the context of a grocery store's signage, which is correct - "Everyday" or "Every Day"?

Tags: orthography, compound-adjectives

Here is an illustrated example:

[image: grocery sign]

A grocer may print information pertaining to a low price deal, on the above pictured sign, and attach it to a shelf for customers to see.

Comment: Whichever one the ad agency picks.

Answer (score 2):

In marketing, the benefit of "everyday low price" is that in THAT store, the customer does not need to wait for a sale, miss a sales price because of not being a member of the "customer loyalty" program, etc., so the sign that reads ***"Everyday Low Price"*** is correct in this context.

Answer (score 0):

*Everyday* as one word is normally used only as an attributive adjective, i.e., directly before a noun. It means 'common or completely normal and often not very interesting'. (http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/everyday)

It is not appropriate in the sign in the question. "Low prices every day" might attract customers.

Comment: But since the use of 'everyday' is nowadays frequently seen on the type of signage mentioned by the OP, I would contend that the lexicographers are lagging behind current usage if they are failing to acknowledge it, not that grocers are misusing the term 'everyday'.

Answer (score 0):

The adjective EVERY modifies the noun DAY. The phrase EVERYDAY means daily happenings or occurrence of something. 
Depending in the context it is being used, it could also be used adverbially.

Answer (score -2):

*Everyday* together is more correct, to space it out is to make it two words.

Comment: By saying "more correct", are you implying that there isn't a 100% correct choice - that both "Everday" and "Every Day" may both be considered proper, yet "Everyday" is the better choice?

Comment: Not to mention that "everyday" and "every day" have different meanings.